# Running "userauth_passwd" function from auth2_passwd.c in OpenSSH

Tags: c, linux, security, openssh

I am trying to figure out what configuration is required of OpenSSH to get the `userauth_passwd` function to run in OpenSSH. I have downloaded it from source (https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable).

I've run the following:

```
autoconf
./configure
make
```

then I run the deamon and try to connect to it with:

```
openssh-portable/sshd -d -p 125
```

then from the client side

```
ssh user@localhost -p 125
```

The connection process through password authentication works just fine, but I know that `userauth_passwd` isn't running because when I edit the source code and add print statements `userauth_passwd` they are not printed. We also tried breaking at that function with GDB and it is clearly not being executed.